# Re-initialise GRUB for non-bootable UEFI zfs 20.04 installation

Tags: boot, grub2

@nickcrabtree

I followed the [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826209/re-initialise-grub-for-non-bootable-uefi-zfs-16-04-installation), but get an error at step 4.3.
4.3 Mount the first disk

```
# mount /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_disk1-part3 /boot/efi
```

I will post the whole context to specify the problem:

```
root@ubuntu:~# zpool import -N -R /mnt rpool
root@ubuntu:~# zfs mount rpool/ROOT/ubuntu
cannot open 'rpool/ROOT/ubuntu': dataset does not exist
root@ubuntu:~# zfs list
NAME                                                                                         USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                                                                                        743G   149G       96K  /mnt
rpool/ROOT                                                                                  24.5G   149G       96K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8                                                                    24.5G   149G     6.47G  /mnt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/srv                                                                1.22M   149G       96K  /mnt/srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/usr                                                                 221M   149G       96K  /mnt/usr
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/usr/local                                                           221M   149G      201M  /mnt/usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var                                                                10.4G   149G       96K  /mnt/var
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/games                                                          1.08M   149G       96K  /mnt/var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/lib                                                            8.30G   149G     4.55G  /mnt/var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/lib/AccountsService                                            1.31M   149G      104K  /mnt/var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/lib/NetworkManager                                             3.62M   149G      396K  /mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/lib/apt                                                         605M   149G     90.1M  /mnt/var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/lib/dpkg                                                        201M   149G     45.3M  /mnt/var/lib/dpkg
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/log                                                            2.01G   149G     1.13G  /mnt/var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/mail                                                           1.08M   149G       96K  /mnt/var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/snap                                                           39.9M   149G     14.1M  /mnt/var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/spool                                                          1.33M   149G      124K  /mnt/var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8/var/www                                                            1.23M   149G      108K  /mnt/var/www
rpool/USERDATA                                                                              68.9G   149G       96K  /mnt

root@ubuntu:~# zfs mount rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2xoyl8
root@ubuntu:~# zfs mount -a
root@ubuntu:~# mount --rbind /dev  /mnt/dev
root@ubuntu:~# mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
root@ubuntu:~# mount --rbind /sys  /mnt/sys
root@ubuntu:~# chroot /mnt /bin/bash --login
root@ubuntu:/# for i in /dev/disk/by-id/*ata*part3; do echo $i; done
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3
root@ubuntu:/# for i in /dev/disk/by-id/*ata*part3; \
      do mkdosfs -F 32 -n EFI ${i}; \
      echo PARTUUID=$(blkid -s PARTUUID -o value \
      ${i}) /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1 >> /etc/fstab; done
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
root@ubuntu:/# mount /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_disk1-part3 /boot/efi
mount: /boot/efi: mount point does not exist.
root@ubuntu:/# mount /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 /boot/efi
mount: /boot/efi: more filesystems detected on /dev/sda3; use -t <type> or wipefs(8).
```

How can I solve this? As the title implies, my system does not boot, I get a lot of errors.

```
root@ubuntu:~# wipefs /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3
DEVICE                                            OFFSET     TYPE       UUID                LABEL
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x52       vfat       DC33-B96E           EFI
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x0        vfat       DC33-B96E           EFI
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x1fe      vfat       DC33-B96E           EFI
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffbf000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffbe000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffbd000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffbc000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffbb000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffba000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb9000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb8000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb7000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb6000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb5000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb4000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb3000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb2000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb1000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffb0000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffaf000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffae000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffad000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffac000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffab000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffaa000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffa9000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffa8000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffa7000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffa6000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffa5000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffa4000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffa3000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffff000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fffe000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fffd000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fffc000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fffb000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fffa000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff9000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff8000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff7000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff6000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff5000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff4000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff3000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff2000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff1000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7fff0000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffef000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffee000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffed000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffec000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffeb000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffea000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe9000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe8000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe7000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe6000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe5000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe4000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe3000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe2000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe1000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_QVO_1TB_S4CZNF0M736535H-part3 0x7ffe0000 zfs_member 1445861048992372300 bpool
```

Comment: My instructions only work for Ubuntu 16.04. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Looks like the developers changed the partition layout in more recent versions so part3 is no longer necessarily the EFI boot partition.

Comment: I used Ubuntu 20.04.